# Insert/update data into two SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert and update data for two tables in one stored procedure where there is one to many relationship between the two tables

Relationship:

[image]

My attempt at insert:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_activateuser] 
    (@code nvarchar(50), 
     @codeuser nvarchar(50),
     @dateactive date,
     @datadd tinyint,
     @dateend date,
     @periodused tinyint,
     @periodremining tinyint,
     @periodadd tinyint,
     @periodfullactive int,
     @active bit)
AS
    INSERT INTO activedate_tb (code, codeuser, dateactive, datadd, dateend,
                               periodused, periodremining, periodadd, periodfullactive, active) 
    VALUES (@code, @codeuser, @dateactive, @datadd, @dateend,
            @periodused, @periodremining, @periodadd, @periodfullactive, @active)

    INSERT INTO activateuser_tb (code, dateactive, datadd, dateend, 
                                 periodused, periodremining, periodadd)
    VALUES (@code, @dateactive, @datadd, @dateend,
            @periodused, @periodremining, @periodadd)
```

My attempt at UPDATE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_activateuser] 
    (@code nvarchar(50), 
     @codeuser nvarchar(50),
     @dateactive date,
     @datadd tinyint,
     @dateend date,
     @periodused tinyint,
     @periodremining tinyint,
     @periodadd tinyint,
     @periodfullactive int,
     @active bit)
AS
    UPDATE activedate_tb 
    SET codeuser = @codeuser,
        dateactive = @dateactive,
        datadd = @datadd, 
        dateend = @dateend,
        periodused = @periodadd,
        periodremining = @periodremining,
        periodadd = @periodadd,
        periodfullactive = @periodfullactive,
        active = @active 
    WHERE code = @code

    UPDATE activateuser_tb 
    SET dateactive = @dateactive,
        datadd = @datadd,
        dateend = @dateend,
        periodused = @periodadd,
        periodremining = @periodremining,
        periodadd = @periodadd  
    WHERE code = @code
```

Comment: What do you mean "error try"?  What error are you getting?  Or do you mean "I have two procs right now, and I want to use one proc to upsert the data"?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Combine the UPDATE statements and INSERT statements into a single stored procedure and call that SP.  If you want to create an UPSERT functionality you can add an IF, check if exists then UPDATE else INSERT.  You can also look into the MERGE function: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/using-the-merge-statement-to-perform-an-upsert.html

Comment: I wanted to inquire about the method of adding and modifying whether you had any errors

Comment: Top 2 that come to mind: 1) Depends on how your relationship is configured, you have to maintain your data integrity.  2) Duplication of primary key on inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the UPSERT Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_activateuser] 
    (@code nvarchar(50), 
     @codeuser nvarchar(50),
     @dateactive date,
     @datadd tinyint,
     @dateend date,
     @periodused tinyint,
     @periodremining tinyint,
     @periodadd tinyint,
     @periodfullactive int,
     @active bit)
AS

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM activedate_tb WHERE code = @code)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO activedate_tb (code, codeuser, dateactive, datadd, 
                                dateend, periodused, periodremining,  
                                periodadd, periodfullactive, active) 
     VALUES(@code,@codeuser, @dateactive, @datadd, @dateend,     
            @periodused, @periodremining, @periodadd,        
            @periodfullactive, @active)

     /* I insert without check because it can’t exists without activedate_tb */
     INSERT INTO activateuser_tb (code, dateactive, datadd, dateend, 
                                  periodused, periodremining, periodadd)
     VALUES (@code, @dateactive, @datadd, @dateend,
             @periodused, @periodremining, @periodadd)
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    UPDATE activedate_tb 
    SET codeuser = @codeuser,
    dateactive = @dateactive,
    datadd = @datadd, 
    dateend = @dateend,
    periodused = @periodadd,
    periodremining = @periodremining,
    periodadd = @periodadd,
    periodfullactive = @periodfullactive,
    active = @active 
    WHERE code = @code

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM activateuser_tb WHERE code = @code /* I used the same update filter*/
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO activateuser_tb (code, dateactive, datadd,dateend,   
                                      periodused, periodremining, 
                                      periodadd)
         VALUES (@code, @dateactive, @datadd, @dateend, @periodused, 
                 @periodremining, @periodadd)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE activateuser_tb 
        SET dateactive = @dateactive,
            datadd = @datadd,
            dateend = @dateend,
            periodused = @periodadd,
            periodremining = @periodremining,
            periodadd = @periodadd  
        WHERE code = @code
    END
END
```